# Operating system not found; can't dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Been using Ubuntu since 2012, dual booting Win7 on my Aspire 4750G. But in early 2014, Ubuntu 13.04 started booting slow (was not able to list down error messages), until it simply would not boot. I could still boot into Win7 though. Re-installed Ubuntu - using version 13.10 last Feb but mistakenly chose "Erase disc and install Ubuntu".

Tried to fix it with Boot Repair and tried reinstalling Win7 but kept getting errors. Used Testdisk to try to recover partitions/files -- it found something, either boot or patition files, which i tried to restore (probably another mistake). Used "FixParts", Tried "fdisk" and "gdisk" but still got errors when trying to partition and format.

After all the tinkering, my laptop ended up with an error on boot, then says "Operating System not found". Pressing F2 during boot, i only get to the Phoenix Secure Core Tiano Setup.

Decided to replace and upgrade to a new HDD and additional DDR3 RAM in August. Installed Ubuntu 14.04 but still get “OS not found” error on startup, although pressing F12 brings me to Boot Menu where I can choose Ubuntu. Upgrade to 14.10 did not fix problem. If I install Win 8.1 instead, it boots up fine but won't let me install Ubuntu because I cant go to live USB  :(

Recently tried Boot-repair again, eventually got "Boot successfully repaired" message (see **"http://paste.ubuntu.com/9622340/"** ) with reminder to “make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file”. I don't know what it means or how to do that. Only difference is that now I get "Booting in insecure mode" message after choosing Ubuntu from Boot Menu (F12).

Help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

- As ask you Question very difficult to search your Question.
- Your problem may be the `BIOS` problem.
- you are first of all update your `BIOS` through this [link](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers)
- Or else also not solved problem the you Format whole `HDD` , that is very difficult because of important data but It is one of the solution.
- then you First install the WIN 7/8.1 whatever you prefer and then you install Ubuntu.
- as my suggestion you install Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 your problem will be solved.
- if you are formatting whole `HDD` and not successfully format the you start live session & From a live session start Gparted Partition Editor from System -> Administration:

[image]

and then just delete all partition then you perform step no 4 in this solution.
If you have any problem with this answer must comment me...:)